# Passing argparse to function which call other function with the same arguments

Tags: python, parameter-passing, command-line-interface, argparse

I was searching similar problem here, but I couldn't find it.
I want to pass arguments from the command line to one function which uses another function with the same arguments.

In my main function I have:

```
def main():
    d = DataProvider()
    data = d.extract_data()
    x = CalculationLogic()
    if args.task == 't1':
        if args.district and args.year:
            x.task1(data,args.year,args.district)
```

In class `CalculationLogic` I have:

```
def task1(self, data, year, district, gender=None):
    result = [stat.amount for stat in data if self.partUpInPeriodFromAndDistrict(stat.status, year, district)]

    print(sum(result) / len(result))
```

and my another function:

```
def partUpInPeriodFromAndDistrict(self, status, year, district):
    return status == 'something' and year <= year and district == district
```

Unfortunately I dont get correct result. How should I pass this argument?

Comment: Please explain this statement `return status == 'something' and year <= year and district == district` with your exampledata: Please show how you call your program. You say you got a incorrect result: Which one? And what do you expect?

Comment: @Manuel, so 'something' is hardcoded and will staty. Left year is a field from API, the right should be from cli. And the same with district. If I hardcode this 2 values it works as it should be.

Comment: You have to show the incorrect result and your expected result, because there is no problem with how you are passing `args.year` and `args.district` to `x.task1`.

Comment: @chepner, the correct result should be 10481.5, but I get 17573.4248....
And I run my program: python main -t t1 -y 2010 -d district_name

Comment: try printing the arguments in main function before calling the functions and see if they are passed correctly

Comment: @DavidSidarous, passed values are correct

Comment: What does this have to do with `argparse`?  I see references to `args.task` etc, where presumably `args` is the `Namespace` set by a `parse_args()` call.  But if you are happy with the values in `args`, but tag this as `argparse`?

Comment: use `print()` to see values in variables in all functions. This way you will see where values are incorrect. You can also check type of every variable - `print( type(variable) )`

Comment: @furas values are the same in every step: main, task1 method and the last method. Well if I hardcode the year (year == 2010) I got the correct result. Is a good way to do year <= year?

Comment: You need to do `year1 <= year2`, with the two variables coming from different sources.  As written you are only passing on `year` variable from one function to the next (with its value coming the `arg.year`).  You don't show another source for a `year` variable.

Comment: `year <= year` is useless - it will always give `True` i.e `1000 <= 1000` You have to use two variables with different names - ie. `year1 <= year2` as in @hpaulj comment.